Querying newly inserted rows by identity column before index update
When inserting a new row into a  Server table with an identity column (auto-increment primary key or any indexed column), what happens if you query the table to retrieve the newly inserted row by its identity value before the index on the identity column is fully updated?
Will the query be able to locate the row efficiently using the index, or will it fall back to a table scan? What are the potential performance implications in this scenario, and how does SQL Server handle such cases?
I would appreciate if you could provide a detailed explanation of the expected behavior and any relevant performance considerations

Yes, check the query plan of your SELECT statement. You can use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this, to get all the details.

@FrankHeikens How is it possible for the database to return the newly inserted row if the indexing process is not yet completed?

if index isn't done, the table or page or row will be locked, so your query will probably wait for the lock to release anyway. This is usually not a problem, unless you insert million of rows

It would be helpful if you could provide the context/scenario you are concerned about, i.e. whats your purpose in wanting to understand this?

Uhh, the question is now about SQL Server instead of PostgreSQL. Can't help you

"before the index on the identity column is fully updated" what does that even mean? Are you referring to a wide-style index update plan, or a narrow plan? Do you have a specific concern, or is this about how you think it works? The session that is making the modifications can read uncommitted data, but it's not going to do so if it's in the middle of a statement. Other sessions won't be able to see it unless they use READ UNCOMMITTED which is dangerous for obvious reasons (if they did so then they could get inconsistent data, eg different rows in the clustered and non-clustered indexes)

I suggest that you read up on the concept of ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability). The short of it is that unless you disable all the safeties with (nolock) or READ UNCOMMITTED, SQL server (and likely any other DBMS) is not going to allow you to access a partially written update. If there is a detected overlap between data being read and data being written, the SQL locking mechanisms will cause one thread to wait until the other completes.
